# C preprocessor macros - definition vs. value portability & practice

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

For compiler-specific code, it's common to see cpp directives such as:

`#if defined (__GNUC__) && (__GNUC__ >= 4)`

which is the preprocessor test I typically use - not exclusively for `__GNUC__`, but it's a common example. Alternatively,

`#if (__GNUC__ >= 4)`

appears to satisfy the same requirements. Are there potential problems with the latter? Not only with gcc, but any standards-conforming preprocessor. Can the LHS be evaluated as a certain value, even if it's not defined? Are there any pitfalls to the second approach that any language lawyers are aware of?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The preprocessor assumes undefined macros to have the value `0` in comparisons, so your simplification is ok in this case. If you want to check against a lower version than 4 in gcc, you may get into trouble though since it would evaluate as `true` with a `<` even if it's not gcc.

I think the reason for using both is also a question of  understandability, if you check

```
#if defined(__GNUC__) && (__GNUC>=4)
```

it's rather obvious you're *not* already in a block with code that only is for GCC, while the simplification

```
#if (__GNUC__ >= 4)
```

does not make that obvious and can be read as a version check only when you already know it's gcc.

Comment: Absolutely agree that the first choice is better since it makes the intent more obvious, and costs nothing. It also avoids potentially incorrect 'fall-through' where multiple compiler / platform cases are evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

In the GNUC case, when you're testing it the other way around, it'll do wrong thing:

```
#if (__GNUC__ < 4)
```

I think this one will be true even if GNUC is not defined.